# Why every time I put a keyframe the skeleton is deformed like this?

Tags: animation, rigging

[image: when i select everything (A) and press (i) to set a keyframe, my Rig look like this]
I haven't been able to animate with this model for weeks, because the same thing always happens, and I don't know what to do

Comment: Hello, maybe you need to also keyframe the feet?

Comment: There isn't enough information to help you. Can you share a video capture of the issue happening ? if you can't, please describe exactly the steps you're taking.

Comment: ok, here is https://imgur.com/a/3jUq6Sy